# How to change the default aws region in boto3 python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to connect to the amazon Rekognition service in region **us-east-1**.
However boto3 always connects to **us-west-2**.

I have run `$ aws configure list` and the credentials and specified region seem to be correct there

[image]

I remember when I first filled in the credentials I did not specify a region and it defaulted to **us-west-2**. Then I edited the file in ~/.aws/config to change the region.
It now has the following contents:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
```

However when I run my script

```
import boto3
bucket='XX' 
photo='FOLDER/XX.jpg'
model='arn:aws:rekognition:us-east-1:XX:project/XX/version/XX/XX'
min_confidence=95
client=boto3.client('rekognition', region_name="us-east-1")
response = client.detect_custom_labels(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket': bucket, 'Name': photo}},
        MinConfidence=min_confidence,
        ProjectVersionArn=model)
```

boto3 always connects to us-west-2

[image]

And then I get the following error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the DetectCustomLabels operation: Cross region access not allowed

How can I tell boto3 to connect to a different region?

Comment: thank you luk2302, I have updated my question with a more complete code snippet.

Comment: Your bucket is probably in the wrong region / in us-west-2 / not in us-east-1 !?

Comment: I just checked that and both the model and the bucket with the image are in "us-east-1".  The only difference between the buckets is that, the bucket with the images is not public.

Comment: Why do you have the arn in bucket and object name?

Comment: When does that screenshot appear? Is it displayed when you run the Python code? What do you mean by "connects to us-west-2"?

Comment: @John: The screenshot comes from my firewall, basically it just shows that boto3 tries to connect to "rekognition.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" and not to "rekognition.us-east-1.amazonaws.com".

Comment: @Ninad: I tried the following combinations: arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME, aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME, s3:::BUCKETNAME, BUCKETNAME. None of them worked.

Comment: If you have any Rekognition resources in us-east-1 e.g. face collections then invoke the relevant describe or list method on that resource in us-east-1 to see if it yields the correct result (for resources in us-east-1).

Comment: Thank you jarmod, I have now resolved the issue by placing the images I want to evaluate into a folder in the same bucket, where the model is stored.

Answer (score 1):

This helped me. Add the line below to your script, before creating your client.

```
client = boto3.setup_default_session(region_name="us-east-1")
```